# How to check a resource's MIME type in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I'm trying to make a function that checks a resource that the user provides, to see if it is a valid audio file.

Everything I've found on here, is related to checking a files MIME type after uploading a file. That is not my goal here.

```js
//insert MIME type checking function here
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const audioURL = urlParams('audiourl') // get audiourl from query (example.com/?audiourl=https://example.com/audio.wav)

if (mimetypecheck()) { // function to check mime type here 
    var audio = new Audio(audioURL);
    audio.play();
} else {
    //tell user invalid audio url, or unsupported audio type
}
```

Comment: Please look at this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime

Comment: You can't check the type without downloading the file, so you might just as well check if the audio starts playing. Especially since checking MIME type isn't fully reliable.

Comment: @GuyIncognito well in theory you could, with a HEAD request.

Comment: With your example here, the “audio URL” appears to be from the same domain, as the one this script is running under. Is that always supposed to be the case? If not, then you can probably rather forget about implementing this using client-side JavaScript - most arbitrary URLs “in the wild”, that your users might input here, will probably not be CORS enabled.

Comment: The example audio url is supposed to be what the user inputs. the url they input could be anything @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been said in comments, the only way to check that a resource points to some *playable* media, is to actually try to play it.

A MIME type won't tell you much, moreover for audio/video media:
you can't be 100% sure that what the container (which is declared by the MIME type) really contains, it could very well be encoded in a codec that the browser can't decode, even if it wrapped in a container the browser should know.

This means that even though a simple HEAD request could tell you for some URLs what the server would send in the Content-Type headers, that wouldn't tell you exactly if the browser would be able to play it. And given most server won't let you read these headers anyway, that doesn't worth the cost of trying to implement this.

For your case the best is thus to try to play it.

So you can rewrite your code to

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const audioURL = urlParams('audiourl') // get audiourl from query (example.com/?audiourl=https://example.com/audio.wav)

const audio = new Audio(audioURL);
audio.onerror = (evt) => {
  //tell user invalid audio url, or unsupported audio type
};
audio.play();
```

Note that we could also have bound to the `catch()` method of the Promise returned by the `HTMLMediaElement.play()` method, but it could actually fire for an other reason (e.g if the user never did interact with the page before in Chrome, or if this code is not in direct response to an user-gesture in Safari).  If you are sure only invalid URLs could be the reason for a failure to play, then you could do

```
const audio = new Audio(audioURL);
audio.play().catch( () => {
  //tell user invalid audio url, or unsupported audio type
});
```